# Calculate dense rank by sum

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, window-functions, dense-rank

Sample data:

| student | marks | subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| stud1 | 100 | sub1 |
| stud1 | 400 | sub2 |
| stud1 | 500 | sub3 |
| stud2 | 200 | sub1 |
| stud2 | 700 | sub2 |
| stud2 | 800 | sub3 |
| stud2 | 900 | sub4 |
| stud3 | 300 | sub1 |
| stud3 | 600 | sub2 |
| stud4 | 1000 | sub1 |

Trying to partition by student and order by sum of marks like below using `dense_rank()`. There are multiple other columns and since the data is big, trying to avoid any joins here.

Expected output:

| student | marks | subject | ds_rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stud1 | 100 | sub1 | 2 |
| stud1 | 400 | sub2 | 2 |
| stud1 | 500 | sub3 | 2 |
| stud2 | 200 | sub1 | 1 |
| stud2 | 700 | sub2 | 1 |
| stud2 | 800 | sub3 | 1 |
| stud2 | 900 | sub4 | 1 |
| stud3 | 300 | sub1 | 3 |
| stud3 | 600 | sub2 | 3 |
| stud4 | 1000 | sub1 | 2 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your current attempt and describe what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate sum and dense_rank in two stages:

```
with cte as (
    select t.*, sum(marks) over (partition by student) as sum_marks
    from t
)
select cte.*, dense_rank() over (order by sum_marks desc) as dense_rankk
from cte
```